# Mapping array of objects to array of arrays with headers using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, concatenation

I want to map an array of objects, which I got from a `json` response of my backend, to an array of arrays, with the first row being an array of headers (titles). I'll use this array to make it downloadable in a `csv` file.

Also, I want to keep away a couple of headers / columns that are not really interesting for the end user to have in their `csv` file.

My code is working fine, but I have the idea that it can be done with more concise code. I'm fine with using ES6 / ES2015, but not really experienced with spread syntax and other ES6 goodies myself, so any suggestions for a better, more modern (functional / reactive?) approach are greatly appreciated.

```js
const originalData = [
  {name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
]

let headers = []
const firstRow = originalData[0]
for (var key in firstRow) {
  if (firstRow.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (!['raw','updated_at'].includes(key)) {
      headers.push(key)
    }
  }
}

const d = originalData.map(function(_, i) {
  return headers.map(function(header) {
    return originalData[i][header]
  }.bind(this))
}.bind(this))

const result = [headers].concat(d)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: "My code is working fine" Then your question would likely be better placed on [codereview.se], but read their help center before doing so.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, didn't know about Code Review, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const originalData = [
  { name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping' },
  { name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail' },
  { name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing' }
]

const headers = Object.keys(originalData[0]).filter(key => !['raw', 'updated_at'].includes(key));
const d = originalData.map(obj => headers.map(key => obj[key]))
const result = [headers, ...d];

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Awesome. This one combines a simpler header creation with using the spread operator to concat headers and content in the right way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could use a closure over the filtered keys and map and concat the arrays.

```js
const fn = (array => (keys => [keys].concat(array.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]))))
           (Object.keys(array[0]).filter(k => !['raw','updated_at'].includes(k)))),
      data = [{ name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping' }, { name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail' }, { name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing' }],
      result = fn(data);


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: since you are currying array do you need a closure around it?

Comment: @Arrow, i need the closure for the keys.

Comment: You are right you do need that closure. I was thinking about doing it this way: 
const keys = data=> Object.keys(data[0]).filter(k => !['raw','updated_at'].includes(k)),
  table = data => (keys => [keys].concat(data.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]))))(keys(data));console.log(table(data));
  However, I end up still needing that closure and I create an extra varable, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is good.  You could simplify the header creation by using `Object.keys`

```
const originalData = [
  {name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
]

const headers = Object.keys(originalData[0])
    .filter(key => !['raw','updated_at'].includes(key)));  
const data = originalData.map(row => headers.map(header => row[header]));

console.log(headers, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalData = [
  {name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
];

const propertiesNeeded = Object.keys(originalData[0]).filter(prop => !['raw', 'updated_at'].includes(prop));
const dataMapped = originalData.map(obj => propertiesNeeded.map(prop => obj[prop]));
const finalArr = [propertiesNeeded, ...dataMapped];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDkPy22J_UAhXLM48KHd2iBbIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg&sig2=vkhC4vvA_audYoyqNRd8zQ) used for recreate the array with `Object.key` and `value` . and [`new Set()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLxYer2J_UAhXFMY8KHQhoBGEQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FSet&usg=AFQjCNGlXBGLqxC3YAUH_NWGCYaxkPxFVg&sig2=bXwEgpyvhOsPrpJ0pYwjdA) method  user for create the key set value .ignore the repeated one `...` its **[spread syntax](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVkY7-2Z_UAhUGNY8KHZf6DGIQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FSpread_operator&usg=AFQjCNFHTdMj01YDZlVyslOCL7g9QRz8zA&sig2=YeAVdJJK7GR6nYj-ZuS5TA)**

```js
const originalData = [
  {name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
]

var result = [[...new Set(...originalData.map(a=> Object.keys(a)))]].concat(originalData.map(a=> Object.values(a)))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. I figured if you know which keys you're after then we can make good use of that.

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Gizmo', species: 'cat', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
]

const desiredKeys = ['name', 'species', 'age', 'skill']

const result = [desiredKeys].concat(data.map(pet => desiredKeys.map(key => pet[key])))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that an object's keys order is not entirely "fixed" by spec.

If your first animal in your `originalData` starts with a `species` property, your whole table will be formatted in that column order...

Therefore I'd advice you to explicitly define your columns in an array, in which order *does* matter.

Note that in the example below I've swapped the property declaration order of Gizmo. Put this data in your own code and the first column will be species. (at least in my browser it is, I guess it can even differ between browsers?)

```js
const data = [
  {species: 'cat', name: 'Gizmo', age: '9', raw: 'G9e76rd', updated_at: '1318874398806', skill: 'sleeping'},
  {name: 'Benny', species: 'dog', age: '3', raw: '98HDo2h', updated_at: '1318874392417', skill: 'chasing tail'},
  {name: 'Oscar', species: 'cat', age: '2', raw: '9da8Ro1', updated_at: '1318874390283', skill: 'meowing'}
]


const getProps = props => obj => 
  props.map(k => obj[k]);
  
const columns = ["name", "species", "age", "skill"];

console.log(
  [columns, ...data.map(getProps(columns))]
);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. For this reason, I understand it's usually preferred to declare the headers manually, but in my case, the actual headers can change a lot (because it's a quickly developing MVP) and the csv output can be 'crude', as long as it's usable for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

A single line of code in an unbroken chain using a filter and reduce.

```js
var unborken = chain => chain.filter((_, i, xx) => 
delete xx[i].updated_at && delete xx[i].raw).reduce((aac, _, i, aa) => 
(i === 0 ? aac.push(Object.keys(aa[i])) && aac.push(Object.values(aa[i])) :
aac.push(Object.values(aa[i])), aac), []);

const originalData = [{
    name: 'Gizmo',
    species: 'cat',
    age: '9',
    raw: 'G9e76rd',
    updated_at: '1318874398806',
    skill: 'sleeping'
  },
  {
    name: 'Benny',
    species: 'dog',
    age: '3',
    raw: '98HDo2h',
    updated_at: '1318874392417',
    skill: 'chasing tail'
  },
  {
    name: 'Oscar',
    species: 'cat',
    age: '2',
    raw: '9da8Ro1',
    updated_at: '1318874390283',
    skill: 'meowing'
  }
];


console.log(unborken(originalData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```